# Hybris: Cannot create ProductBundle Item Type that extends ProductModel

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I wanted to implement custom dynamic attribute handler class for `ProductBundle` class, but it expects `AbstractItemModel` type instead of my `ProductBundle`:

```
public class BundlePriceAttributeHandler extends AbstractDynamicAttributeHandler<Double, ProductModel> {
```

It gives `error: type argument ProductModel is not within bounds of type-variable MODEL hybris`

Then I tried

```
    <itemtype code="ProductBundle" autocreate="true" generate="true" extends="ProductModel">
        <attributes>
            <attribute qualifier="bundlePrice" type="java.lang.Double">
                <persistence type="dynamic" attributeHandler="bundlePriceAttributeHandler"/>
            </attribute>
        </attributes>
    </itemtype>
```

but, there is error `YComposedType due to missing super type 'ProductModel'` (even using `de.hybris.platform.core.model.product.ProductModel`)

if I try extend just `"Product"` my `ProductBundle` will extend just `Product` jalo class not `ProductModel`, and it will cause `error: type argument ProductModel is not within bounds of type-variable MODEL hybris` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this error

`YComposedType due to missing super type 'ProductModel' (even using de.hybris.platform.core.model.product.ProductModel)`

It is saying that type ProductModel is not available, and that's correct. This platform's default itemtype name is "product," not "ProductModel".

Naming convention follows as below:

[image]

so correct entry should be as below.

```
<itemtype code="ProductBundle" autocreate="true" generate="true" extends="Product">
                <attributes>
                    <attribute qualifier="bundlePrice" type="java.lang.Double">
                        <persistence type="dynamic" attributeHandler="bundlePriceAttributeHandler"/>
                    </attribute>
                </attributes>
            </itemtype>
```

and attribute handler class :

```
package com.customer.attributeHandler;

import com.core.model.ProductBundleModel;
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.model.attribute.DynamicAttributeHandler;

public class BundlePriceAttributeHandler implements DynamicAttributeHandler<Double, ProductBundleModel> {

    @Override
    public Double get(ProductBundleModel model) {
        //Random return
        return model.getAverageRating();
    }

    @Override
    public void set(ProductBundleModel model, Double aDouble) {

    }
}
```

Bean entry as below:

```
<alias name="bundlePriceAttributeHandler" alias="bundlePriceAttributeHandler"/>
    <bean class="com.customer.attributeHandler.BundlePriceAttributeHandler" id="bundlePriceAttributeHandler"/>
```